# jQuery Sticky Plugin Variable Top Spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, settimeout, sticky

I'm using the [jQuery sticky plugin](http://stickyjs.com/) to stick the menu and contact information to the top. The site is responsive, so spacing from the top for the menu changes. I'm trying to do different spacing based on the CSS value of the contact info, but it's not working. I was pretty sure my jQuery was correct...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){   
 function checkForFloat()
  {
    setTimeout(checkForFloat, 100);
    if($("#contact").css("float") === "none") {
      $("#headerbg2").sticky({topSpacing:180});   
    }
    else if (!$("#contact").css("float") === "none") {
      $("#headerbg2").sticky({topSpacing:120});
    }
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1j9cdsro/

Comment: provide a demo using https://jsfiddle.net/ or http://codepen.io/ to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Here you go. As you see it works for #headerbg1, but not on #headerbg2: http://jsfiddle.net/1j9cdsro/

Comment: are you trying to stick the blue bar below the lightblue one? like this http://jsfiddle.net/0x7nsLh0/

Comment: yes, I'm trying to stick it but not as simply as you did. Like I mentioned, I want it to stick when a certain CSS condition is met. In this case float: none;

Comment: ok well in the demo the contact never floats to none, you can see it when you change to check for right -- http://jsfiddle.net/wejfhkdg/  -- so the question is, when does it change to none???

Comment: pay close attention. there is a media query there. It floats to none at < 450px wide. I explained it in the original question.

Comment: Ok i didn't see the media query. So the flaw in your code is ((!$("#contact").css("float") === "none")) should be ($("#contact").css("float") != "none") or just (else) -- http://jsfiddle.net/72j5fL3g/  -- it works now

Comment: thanks but it didn't change the spacing on top depending on the float. The spacing seems to be the same in both occasions.

Comment: take a closer look -- http://jsfiddle.net/9fz6u64h/

Comment: I did, and it's 50 top spacing on both occasions. Not 120.

Comment: if you look at the documentation, if you make changes to the stick ie resize the window you need to use ($("#headerbg2").unstick()) first so it clears it first. i put in an on resize event in the demo to demonstrate it dynamically -- http://jsfiddle.net/2qe4zg21/

Comment: you sir are a saint. How do I upvote you?

Comment: check answer because it also need to use ($("#headerbg2").sticky('update')) to update the sticky otherwise  the (unstick) by it self wont work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make Dynamic changes to the sticky from the documentation it needs to unstick first and updated

```
$("#headerbg2").unstick() &  $("#headerbg2").sticky('update')
```

this also needs to change `(!$("#contact").css("float") === "none")` to either `($("#contact").css("float") != "none")` or `else { .. }`

**Demo** with dynamic window resize

http://jsfiddle.net/w2jv7szg/

**Code**

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#headerbg1").sticky({
          topSpacing: 0
      });

      function checkForFloat() {


          if ($("#contact").css("float") === "none") {
              $("#headerbg2").sticky({
                  topSpacing: 50
              });
          } else {
              $("#headerbg2").sticky({
                  topSpacing: 120
              });
          }
      }
      setTimeout(checkForFloat, 1000);


      window.addEventListener('resize', function (event) {
            $("#headerbg2").unstick()

          if ($("#contact").css("float") === "none") {
              $("#headerbg2").sticky({
                  topSpacing: 50
              });
              $("#headerbg2").sticky('update')
          } else {
              $("#headerbg2").sticky({
                  topSpacing: 120
              });
              $("#headerbg2").sticky('update')
          }
      })

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
 function checkForFloat()
  {
    setTimeout(checkForFloat, 100);
    if($("#contact").css("float") === "none") {
      $("#headerbg2").sticky({topSpacing:180});   
    }
    else if ($("#contact").css("float") !== "none") {
      $("#headerbg2").sticky({topSpacing:120});
    }
  }
});
```

Changed the "!" position.

Comment: does not make a difference